# Is it possible to dynamically expand a scalar assignment depending on the size of an array?

Tags: perl

So, here's the deal.  I have an array, let's call it

```
@array = ('string1','string2','string3','string4');
```

etc., etc.  I have no way of knowing how large the array is or what the contents are, specifically, except that it is an array of strings.

I also have a variable which needs to be changed depending on the size and contents of the array.

Here's a sample easy assignment of that variable, along with the array that would have generated the assignment:

```
@array = ('string1','string2','string3');

$var = Some::Obj1(Some::Obj2('string1'),
                 Some::Obj2('string2'), 
                 Some::Obj2('string3'));
```

Then, if for instance, I had the following @array,

```
@array = ('string1','string2','string3','string4','string5');
```

My assignment would need to look like this:

```
$var = Some::Obj1(Some::Obj2('string1'),
                 Some::Obj2('string2'), 
                 Some::Obj2('string3'), 
                 Some::Obj2('string4'), 
                 Some::Obj2('string5'));
```

Can you guys think of *any* way that something like this could be implemented?

Comment: You're saying `Some::Obj` will accept either a string argument, or a list of values in its own result format.  Can you modify the function to accept an array of strings instead?

Comment: Sorry, that probably wasn't super clear. They're different objects.

Comment: Then you should edit the question to show that they are different objects.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, if all you need is to turn some strings into a list of objects inside an object... Why not map?

```
my @array = ('string1','string2','string3','string4','string5');
my $var = Some::Obj1(map { Some::Obj2($_) } @array);
```

Comment: Hm.  I don't doubt that this is correct, but I'm still having issues with my program.  Time to dig some more, I guess...

Comment: If this does not work, then neither does your manual assignment.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you just do

```
$var = Some::Obj1(map(Some::Obj2($_), @array));
```

That produces the exact same result as the code you wrote:

```
$var = Some::Obj1(Some::Obj2('string1'),
             Some::Obj2('string2'), 
             Some::Obj2('string3'), 
             Some::Obj2('string4'), 
             Some::Obj2('string5'));
```

Of course, it goes without saying that you should use either `my` or `our` before the variable as appropriate if you are initializing it for the first time. If you wish to perform more complicated operations using `map`, an entire block of code can be enclosed in braces and the comma omitted, i.e.,

```
map {operation 1; operation 2; ...; final operation stored as result;} @array
```